# Linear search vs strlen

Tags: c, pointers

In one of my assignments, I was required to use linear search to find the last char of a string and set it to a pointer, it is just a simple string eg `"blah blah blah"`. To do this I used

`int length = strlen(string);`

to find the length, then used a for loop

```
for (i=1;i<length;i++){
    if (string[i]==0){;
        end_pointer = &string[i-1];
    }
```

Is there any difference between using linear search for 0 to set the pointer as opposed to using length:

```
end_pointer = &string[length-1];
```

Comment: `if (string[i]=0)` is not correct. You should use `==` for comparison, not `=`.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the assignment,  I think when your instructor says linear search for the end of the string, he most likely means doing an unbounded search until string[i] == '\0', which is the standard end of string character, else it really isn't a SEARCH, but more a "dumb" loop.

Comment: `strlen` already does a linear search for `'\0'`. I'm guessing your instructor doesn't want you to use `strlen`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what your professor is really looking for is:

```
int i = 0;
while( '\0' != string[i] ) i++;
```

for the search

Assign after the looping has completed for best efficiency:

```
char * end_pointer = &string[i - 1];
```

Comment: Except if `i == 0` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to explain how strings are stored in C.

Since strings can, in general, have arbitrary length, there needs to be a way to represent that length along with the content of the string. The two most trivial ways of representing the length are as follows.

- explicitly keep track of length
- use a special token to denote the end of string

The C language went with the second option. Specifically, `'\0'` is used to denote the end of the string. So if you have a `char * p`, then that is a pointer<sup>†</sup> that points to the first character; the second character in the string is `p[1] == *(p+1)`, and so on.

So how do you get the length of the string? In the first method of representing strings (NOT the C way), it's already explicitly available. With C strings, you have to start at the beginning and count how many characters there are until the special token (`'\0'` in C). This is called a linear search for the end of string token.

`strlen` implements such a linear search, but it sounds like you are not supposed to use it. Regardless, `strlen` doesn't actually give you the pointer to the end of the string; you would have to compute it as

```
char *endPtr = string + strlen(string);
```

In this case, `endPtr` will actually point to the null-termination character, which is just past the end of the string. This is a common paradigm in C for specifying ranges: the start of the range (`string` in this case) is usually *inclusive*, and the end of the range (`endPtr` in this case) is usually *exclusive*.

---

<sup>†</sup>
 <sub>`char *` could just be a pointer to a single `char` and not necessarily a string, but that doesn't concern us here.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The difference between using a linear search for `'\0'` to set the pointer as opposed to using length derived from `strlen()` is a slight potential efficiency change.

If one rolls their own code or uses the standard library function `strlen()`, it is still the same order of complexity O(n).  If anything, `srtrlen()` has potential of being more efficient.

---

If the goal is to create you own code and point to the last `char` in a string (not the `'\0'`), handle `""` as a special case, otherwise perform a simple loop;

```
char *LastCharPointer(char *string) {
  if (*string == '\0') {
    return NULL;
  }
  do {
    string++;
  } while (*string);
  return string - 1;
}
```

If the goal is to point to the null chanracter `'\0'`:

```
char *NullCharPointer(char *string) {
  while (*string) string++;
  return string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming the code you pasted above is not the actual code you wrote, it would be :

```
for( i = 0; i < strlen( string ); i++ ) {
   if( string[ i ] ){
      end_pointer = &string[i - 1];
   }
}
```

You can do this in two ways :

```
char * end_pointer = &string[ strlen( string ) - 1 ]
```

or

```
for( i = 0; string[ i ] ; i++ );
char * end_pointer = &string[ i - 1 ]
```

Effectively when you call strlen( ), it runs in linear time to calculate the length. Once you have the length you can index into the string directly or, you could yourself search for the terminating '\0' character. All this works assuming that your string is null-terminated.
EDIT : The second option had a missing ";".

Comment: Your second answer however, is exactly like mine that I have been voted down for, except yours will take longer, as you assign end pointer each iteration through your loop!

Comment: When I started answering the question, there were no replies, I saw yours just after I submitted mine. Anyways, thanks for pointing out the for loop mistake, I missed typing in a ";" after the for loop. Yes, it is exactly the same thing as your while loop snippet.